# Getting data from BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-broadcast

I am calling a function `f1()` in another `app1` from `app2` by implementing a custom `BroadcastReceiver` in `app1`. How to get return data from that `f1()` to `app2` through this `BroadcastReceiver`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Send data in broadcast intent:

```
Intent it1=new Intent();
it1.setAction("check_values");
it1.putExtra("data_key1",data1);
it1.putExtra("data_key2",data2);
sendBroadcast(it1);
```

Check in broadcast receiver:

```
if(intent.getAction().equals("check_values"))
{
    data1=intent.getStringExtra("data_key1");
    data2=intent.getStringExtra("data_key2");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should implement same broadcast receiver in your app and call this from that other app's function.

Comment: But how to send the value to app2?

Comment: Add values in intent and send to broadcast.